# Emacs org-clock-in not working: Symbol's function definition is void: org-end-of-meta-data

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I am new to emacs and org mode and I was trying to clock my items.

When I use C-c C-x C-i to clock in one item, the buffer said:

Symbol's function definition is void: org-end-of-meta-data

Here is my emacs and org mode version:

Org-mode version 8.2.10 (release_8.2.10 @ /Users/XXX/org-mode/lisp/)

GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin15.4.0, NS apple-appkit-1404.46) of 2016-05-09 on XXX-MacBook-Pro.local

Many thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Emacs questions belong on [emacs.se].

Comment: @TobySpeight: No, Emacs question do not belong only on emacs.SE. There is nothing wrong with posting an Emacs question on SO (or other SE sites, such as superuser). The thing to avoid is posting the same question to two such sites. Check tag `emacs` for SO, to see about as many recent Emacs question as are on emacs.SE.

Comment: It is truly unfortunate that people who read this thread are discouraging a new forum participant from joining stackoverflow and contributing in the future to the `emacs` and `org-mode` tags.  The poor response by this community is the reason these tags are becoming extinct -- people are so strict about seeing a programming question, and people are so unwilling to take the time to answer such seemingly simple questions.  People who follow these tags would rather see no new posts, than lend a helping hand.  Perhaps these tags should simply become extinct and that will be that -- the end!

Comment: The error you are seeing tells you that the file that defines function `org-end-of-meta-data` has not been loaded. Find out which file/library that is and `require` that library in your init file. Perhaps it is enough to just turn on `org-mode` (dunno - I don't use Org)?

Comment: @Drew Thanks so much for your explanation! I found a way to get around it and it is inspired by your interpretation.

Comment: @Drew, *some* Emacs questions are welcome here - those that about programming in Emacs Lisp, or about using Emacs to edit and build software.  But this question contains none of the elements that qualify a question for Stack Overflow (lack of code is always a warning sign), and would definitely be more appropriate on [emacs.se] or (as a problem with an installed extension), [su].

Answer (score 6):

Thanks so much for Drew's answer! I checked org-mode's updates on their website and realized that it could be a version issue. I updated to version 8.3.5, and the problem resolved. I guess it is because org-end-of-meta-data was not yet introduced in my previous version.